# Anchors don't work in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

Thanks for taking the time.

I implemented css bootstrap and got a nice fixed menu on top of my one page scrolling website. Just to make sure users instinctively see the navigation, I copied the menu below the header as well. Works well on every browser I have but IE 10.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="text-center"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-info">
        <a href="#news" style="color:white">123123</a>
    </button>   
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-warning">
        <a href="#articles" style="color:white">13132123</a>
    </button>  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger">
        <a href="#video" style="color:white">12313123</a>
    </button>      
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-success">
        <a href="#zaprimer" style="color:white">ЗА 132123123</a>
    </button>    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-info">
        <a href="#create" style="color:white">12312313</a>
    </button>      
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-warning">
        <a href="#donate" style="color:white">123123123</a>
    </button> 
</div>
```

The div's are named like this:

```
<div class="news-holder cf" id="news">
```

They are closed and everything. I am completely new to web design so I don't know what's happening. It's bizarre.

Comment: Do you have any customised CSS in the site?

Comment: Yes! 
one is pretty much this http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-one-page-wonder/css/one-page-wonder.css 
I've modified this template. 
Some of my own too but it doesn't affect the divs


'<style> 



  .navbar-custom {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #ECF5FF;
   }



.featurette-divider {
    
    margin: 30px 0; height: 1px; 
    border: 0; border-top: 1px solid grey;}


.morepadding {
    padding: 70px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #8AC007; 
}

.reddy {

    border: 2px solid orange; 
}

</style>'

Comment: Actually this as well: http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/vertical-news-slider/css/vertical.news.slider.css?v=1.0 
It's a free jquery slider

Comment: I removed each css file, incl my <style> in the html and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by #recursive a link should not be in a button.

Further more if this is a menu you most certainly should not be using button and avoid inline styles.

also check that you have div's on page with the id of news, articles etc.

if you need further assistance please supply more of your code.

---

try this.

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="text-center">
    <li class="btn btn-default btn-info">
      <a href="#news" style="color:white">123123</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn btn-default btn-warning">
      <a href="#articles" style="color:white">13132123</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn btn-default btn-danger">
      <a href="#video" style="color:white">12313123</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn btn-default btn-success">
      <a href="#zaprimer" style="color:white">ЗА 132123123</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn btn-default btn-info">
      <a href="#create" style="color:white">12312313</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn btn-default btn-warning">
      <a href="#donate" style="color:white">123123123</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just wrapped the button in the a href like this: 
<a href="#articles" style="color:white"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">123123</button></a> and it worked. But yours is less code so I may implement it.

Comment: Yeah links and buttons just shouldn't be near each other at all. You should just style your link to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` elements are not allowed inside of `<button>` elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element

> there must be no interactive content descendant.

That's likely to be related to the problem.  Since anchors have been well supported for decades.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem exactly. It works now.